# Random variable with infinite expectation $\mathbb E(\vert X\vert)=\infty.$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to show that when $\mathbb E(\vert X\vert)=\infty$ and $X_i$ are iid copies of $X$ then necessarily

$$\limsup_n \frac{\vert \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \vert}{n}=\infty.$$

However, this is tricky as we cannot assume that they have the sign.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Are you willing to assume that $EX_i$ is defined in the sense either $EX_i^{+} <\infty$ or $EX_i^{-} <\infty$?

Comment: actually no, since otherwise the part that is infinite, will just have much more mass.

Comment: But maybe you can still show us your proof with that assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof assuming that $EX$ is defined (i.e.$EX^{+} <\infty$ or $EX^{-} <\infty$) : Either $EX^{+} =\infty$ or $EX^{-} =\infty$. In the first case $EX_k^{-} <\infty$ and $\frac  1 n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \min {\{X_k, N\}} \to E\min {\{X_1, N\}}$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$ for each $N$ (by SLLN). Since $E\min {\{X_1, N\}}$ can be made as large as we want and  $\lim \sup \frac  1 n |\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_k| \geq \lim \sup \frac  1 n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_k \geq \lim \sup \frac  1 n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \min {\{X_k, N\}} $ we get the result immediately. The case $EX^{-} =\infty$ follows by changing $(X_n)$ to $(-X_n)$.